# BindingContext and a Multiselected datagridview

Tags: c#, binding

Getting the current object with BindingContext is no problem but what do I do when I have selected many rows in the datagridview? How do I iterate through each object?

Comment: It will surely help WPF users :) The question sounds more likely related to winforms.

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't easy or fun. Binding multiple selected rows in the datagrid isn't supported by default. I use MultiSelectBehavior from Functional Fun:

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html

These are my notes to get it to work:

To get this to work, I did this:

Add this namespace definition to the view:
xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:FunctionalFun.UI.Behaviours;assembly=MultiSelectBehavior"

Within the datagrid, add the last two lines shown here (ff:... and SelectionMode....):
            
                       **ff:MultiSelectorBehaviours.SynchronizedSelectedItems="{Binding SelectedTasks}"** 
                       **SelectionMode="Extended"**

Note: In the view model, SelectedTasks cannot be null, even when first declared.

No:private ObservableCollection selectedTasks;

Yes: private ObservableCollection selectedTasks = new ObservableCollection();

And this is some actual code that works:

```
xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:FunctionalFun.UI.Behaviours;assembly=MultiSelectBehavior"

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedApplicationServer.ApplicationsWithOverrideGroup}"
                  ff:MultiSelectorBehaviours.SynchronizedSelectedItems="{Binding SelectedApplicationsWithOverrideGroup}"
                  SelectionMode="Extended">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Application.Name}" Header="Name" Width="150" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Application.Version}" Header="Version" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CustomVariableGroup.Name}" Header="Override Group" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Hope it helps.

Edit: I simply added the Functional Fun code as a project within my solution, and then I referenced it within my view project:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had a problem using the above code.  I was adding new items to the SynchronizedSelectedItems object.  To resolve the problem, I stopped creating new items, and started adding the items from the ItemSource object.  So I looped through the ItemSource to find the right item to add to the SyncronizedSelectedItems rather than saying I know the ItemSource contains something which equals XX, so create a new item from XX and add it to the SyncronizedSelectedItems.   Anyway, thanks for the code, love it, works great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataGridView is bound to a `BindingSource`, using the `DataMember` property this way :

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = someBindingSource;
myDataGridView.DataMember = "SomeCollectionProperty";
```

Then you can retrieve the list of bound items behind your `DataGridView`:

```
IList dataBoundItems = 
          ((CurrencyManager)grid.BindingContext[grid.DataSource, grid.DataMember]).List;
```

You may also want to cast this list to an `IEnumerable<T>` using :

```
var myItems = dataBoundItems.OfType<myClass>();
```